# With Event Sourcing, how to invalidate and correct an event representing a report/claim/record?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I am new to Event Sourcing and I am considering using it for an industrial application to track connections between tanks, pipes and various physical components in a production facility.

My initial idea was to use commands and events such as `ConnectPipeToTank` → `PipeConnectedToTank`. However, the “book of records” is not the application itself but what physically happens in the production facility. Therefore, it feels more appropriate to use commands and events such as `ReportPipeConnectedToTank` → `PipeConnectedToTankReported`.

Such an event is still a fact but what the fact really is about is nothing more than a report/claim/record that a user has made at a given point in time about something that happened in another point in time. Other users will take decisions based on these reports.

But of course, nothing guarantees that these reports are accurate (typos, malicious entries, incomplete knowledge at the time of entry, etc.). So we need a way to correct a report without removing the knowledge that the report was incorrect at some point in time: we need to be able to amend a report. We want a bi-temporal system to be able to perform audits.

In event sourcing, events are immutable so what is the correct way to invalidate and correct events representing reports?

I thought about 2 ways of dealing with this:

I provide a new couple of command and event to correct a report
`CorrectPipeConnectedToTankReport` → `PipeConnectedToTankReportCorrected`
and also to invalidate a report
`InvalidatePipeConnectedToTankReport` → `PipeConnectedToTankReportInvalidated`
where those events would reference the initial event.

Or, I provide a new generic event to invalidate any other event representing a report: `ReportInvalidated` that would reference the event in question.
And then, to correct a report
`CorrectPipeConnectedToTankReport` → `ReportInvalidated`, `PipeConnectedToTankReported`
and to invalidate a report
`InvalidatePipeConnectedToTankReport` → `ReportInvalidated`.

That does not seem like a problem specific to my domain so I imagine there is a proper way of doing it.

Comment: That's a concern I had for a long time, but which I never took the time to answer for myself or seek answers. The solution you propose is what came to my mind, but there's a lot of hidden complexity. For instance, what if the system enforces some invariants like a maximum number of connected pipes b/c pipes only have x connectors in the real life then perhaps changing a single event cannot bring consistency in the system meaning you have to create a mechanism to batch a number of corrections at the same time. That might become quite complicated if there are rules on the sequence of events.

Comment: Furthermore, reports ran of as of a specific date would still need to consider events of the future (corrections). Another issue I see is that what you really want to do is patch a command, not an event. Commands wont always match 1-1 with events and correcting such processes become more complex. Also, if you allow to replace an event it means they must have individual IDs now and the domain must be aware, unless you decide to patch the streams at a lower level.

Comment: There are tons of complex considerations for fixing arbitrary past states. It's clearly not as simple as fixing account balances. Perhaps Greg talks about this in his event sourcing book about versioning (haven't had the time to read it yet). I'll keep thinking about that one when I have time...

Comment: @plalx: your comments are very interesting. Greg Young mentions an [example](https://leanpub.com/esversioning/read#leanpub-auto-more-complex-example) close to what could be considered as a report event.

Answer (score 3):

Martin Fowler answers this question in his website about [Retroactive Event](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/RetroactiveEvent.html).

> […] the retroactive event is always an event in itself. […] Consider the rejected event case - in effect this is a delete to the event in the event log. However the whole point of the event log is that we never delete an event. So what we can do is insert a rejection event to the log […]

So, to *reject* (or invalidate) a report/claim/record event, simply publish a `EventRejected` that contains the `event_id` of the event that needs to be rejected.

To *correct* a report/claim/record event, first publish a `EventRejected` that contains the `event_id` of the event that needs to be rejected and then publish a new report/claim/record event with the corrected data.

Answer (score 1):

> I am new to Event Sourcing and I am considering using it for an industrial application to track connections between tanks, pipes and various physical components in a production facility.
>
> the “book of records” is not the application itself but what physically happens in the production facility.

A good talk to review is Greg Young's discussion of [event sourcing for warehouse systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=10m48s).

My recommendation: it will probably be easier to think of the messages that travel to your system from the production facility as *events*, rather than commands.  The book of record is the facility, your solution is maintaining a cached copy of that book of record.

Things are further complicated, in your case, by the fact that the messages you receive may not be accurate.  That probably means some sort of *Compensating Event* to handle data errors ~ perhaps by explicitly modeling both effective time and reporting time.

It could be as straight forward as supporting backdated events and perhaps as simple `ReportRetracted` event to signal that some other event in the pipeline should be ignored.

Comment: To clarify: my system is (will be) the main production facility system, and is located in the facility itself. Those reports are entered by human users directly in the system. My solution is neither the book of record nor a cached copy of it. It is the _main representation_ of that book of record. Hope that makes sense.